# Как рассчитвается flex-grow в браузере google-chrome?

Tags: html, css

```css
   .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid orangered;
    font-size: 3em;
}

   .item1 {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(76, 168, 23);
}

    .item2 {
    flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item1">CSS</div>
   <div class="item2">is</div>
</div>
```

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся в рассчётах.

Есть формула: ширина элемента = ((flex-grow элемента / сумма значений flex-grow) * доступное пространство) + исходная ширина элемента.

Исходная ширина элемента `item1 = 85px`

Исходная ширина элемента `item2 = 32px`

Сумма значений `flex-grow = 3`

Доступное пространство = `500px` (ширина флекс-контейнера) - (`85px` + `32px` (ширина флекс-элементов)) = `383px`.

Допустим рассчитаем `item2` = ((2/3) * `383px`) + `32px` = `287px`.

Браузер же выводит значение ширины элемента `333px`.

Comment: вы считаете для `flex-basis: auto`, но у вас `flex-basis: 0%`

Comment: @Spatz, спасибо огромное! Столько времени голову ломал.